# Mongoose: Async Validation

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm designing an app with Express + Mongo.
I'm wondering that if is there any sync validation feature of mongoose?

Think that such a scenario,
I'm checking existing of email path with my custom validation statement like;

```
UserSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, fn) {
    const User = mongoose.model('User');
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('email')) {
      User.find({ email: email }).exec(function (err, users) {
        fn(!err && users.length === 0);
      });
    } else fn(true);
  }, 'Email already exists');
```

On the documentation of mongoose,

> Validation is asynchronously recursive; when you call Model#save,
>   sub-document validation is executed as well. If an error occurs, your
>   Model#save callback receives it

The validation of email-checking of course must be sync. If it is not, it will cause a big incosistency. If two of users requests simultaneously with the same email, then mongoose will accept two of them.

Is setting the `unique` on the model field definition of model solves problem?

I'm asking this because in my application there is a matching system.
If the condition satisfies, i'm matching two of users and creating a match document like;

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a2b30396aa5a754ccbfe63c"),
    "checkin" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a2b2ff96aa5a754ccbfe639"), 
        ObjectId("5a2b2fea6aa5a754ccbfe638")
    ],
    "user" : [ 
        ObjectId("5a29ece139205a12b5afd47e"), 
        ObjectId("5a29924bf3dc4b8dd881a307")
    ],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-09T00:37:13.221Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

It is very dangerious that constructing a `match` entity with same users.
For controlling the duplication, firstly i'm querying the recent collection to checking if there are two user's match entity exists, if not then constructing a match entity and saving it into collection.

But yesterday i've discovered a bug, when two client request same time, the operation behaves async and constructing duplicate of documents.

Please tell me how can i deal with this problem. 
I know modelling the match relationship document into user's document as a sub document is solves problem. Because then i'm using `findAndUpdate` and i'm sure updating of mongoDB on a single document is `atomic`.

Thanks for your considerations,

Comment: Have you checked after declaring email unique?

Comment: No. Especially i assuming that mongodb will handle the uniqueness of the email field on back-end level. But i'm curious about can i apply same logic onto match collection. But i'm pretty new on mongoose and nodejs with a traditional SQL background.

Answer (score 0):

"unique" property is not used for validation. it just helps for faster query. if you set `unique:true` for your email, when you query an email address, once mongoose finds the right email it will stop querying. Because it knows that it is unique.

for validation of email, I would suggest you using very popular npm package named validator:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator

here is how to implement it in your schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const validator = require("validator");

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase:true,
    validate(value) {
      if (!validator.isEmail(value)) {
        throw new Error("email is not valid");
      }
    }
  },
});
```

validate is mongoose custom validator. inside of this we use validator pack method. for the value of email, validator package checks if it is not a valid email,

```
!validator.isEmail(value)
```

this will return false so mongoose will throw an error message